# oracle SQL rank(), or ROW_NUMBER() by multiple partition keys

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have a table having customer segment info (5 factor/character columns), have division_brand info (2 factor/character  columns) and hope 
I can rank different product_category by cate_qty and cate_margin within each customer segment and division_brand segment(9 columns). Could I have some suggestion how to make the ranking (rank() or rownumber())  more efficient?
in reality i have more dimension in customer segment having 7 columns

here is an example

```
create table prod_cate_rank as
select
             gender
           , age_group
           , div1_rev_bucket
           , div2_rev_bucket
           , div3_rev_bucket
           , division_name
           , brand
           , product_category
           , cat_revenue
           , cat_margin
           , cat_qty
           ,ROW_NUMBER()over (partition by 
                                        gender
                                        , age_group
                                        , div1_rev_bucket
                                        , div2_rev_bucket
                                        , div3_rev_bucket
                                        , division_name
                                        , brand
                            order by cat_qty desc, cat_margin desc) as rn
    from seg_product_info
```

thank you!
should i use any technique like:
1.

```
partition by hash
                     (
                                  division_name
                                 ,brand
                     )
                     partitions 32
                     nologging;
```

or 
2.

```
partition by hash
             (
                           division_name
                                 ,brand
             )
             partitions 32
             nologging
;

CREATE INDEX core
on
             seg_product_info
             (
                            gender
               , age_group
               , div1_rev_bucket
               , div2_rev_bucket
               , div3_rev_bucket
               , division_name
             )
;
```

Comment: the `partition by` clause in an analytic function doesn't have anything to do with table partitioning. I think you may have confused the two. Instead, it's more like the `group by` in an aggregate query. As it stands, your question isn't clear; what are you hoping to achieve? Please edit your question to add in sample input data and expected output.

Comment: Your query doesn't have any WHERE clause, so it must read all rows from the table, sort them by partition columns + order by columns and number them. Since the query also must retrieve columns that don't paticipate in PARTITION BY + ORDER BY clauses (`select ... brand , product_category  , cat_revenue  , cat_margin  , cat_qty`, so the index is useless in this case (I suppose that such an index would contain most of the columns from the table), Full Table Scan is probably the most efficient method, and you must live with it.